# Why does my spring boot web application fail to load its configuration properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-applications

I have created a trivial example spring boot web application and it is running well. That is, the web application starts, the controllers respond to requests by calling services and returning results. This gives me confidence that I have the basic right. I am now trying to add external configuration via an `application.properties` file and I simply cannot get it to load.

I am using Spring Boot 2, Spring 5, Eclipse and Maven. My `pom.xml` contains:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My web application class is:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.example.root")
public class ExampleWebApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleWebApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

My service class where I try and load the environment is:

```
@Service
public class DataService {
    @Value("${com.example.property}")
    private String p1;
    @Value("com.example.property")
    private String p2;
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    public DataService() {
        ...
    }
 }
```

My `application.properties` file contains:

```
com.example.property=value
```

When the web application is built, `application.properties` is correctly copied into `WEB-INF/classes`.

When the application runs and I put a break point in the service's constructor, `p1`, `p2` and `env` are `null`. Any suggestions on how I might debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging through contructor won't work. As the values are injected through reflection, which happens after constructor is called.

If you want to debug try `@PostConstruct`

```
@PostConstruct
  public void someMethodName() {
    System.out.println(p1);
  }
```

The way you are injecting for p2(`@Value("com.example.property")`) is wrong. p1(`@Value("${com.example.property}")`) is the right way

Comment: Thanks - this solved my problem. I was previously initialising some attributes in the constructor. I've moved this to a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` and all is well.

Comment: Great answer @pvpkiran.

Answer (score 0):

The values are injected after the constructor is finished (you know, so the object has been constructed), so you wouldn't see any values inside the constructor of course.

For `@Autowired` properties you could switch to constructor injection, which would allow you to see at least `env` having a value. It might be possible to inject the `@Value` properties like that as well, but so far it's unclear whether you even have a problem, or you just think you have a problem because you don't see injected values inside the constructor.

Comment: And you need to add a method with `@PostConstruct` if you want a proper breakpoint after bean initialization.